# Accessing to parent var of my module in node.js

Tags: node.js, module

I'm creating a module in node.js and i would like to access to the variables of the level where is being loaded the module.

```
var externalvar = 12345;

var mymodule = require('mymodule');
```

Is possible access to `externalvar` inside of `mymodule`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
var externalvar = 12345;

var mymodule = require('mymodule')(externalvar);
```

Inside your module:

```
module.exports = function(val) {
    console.log(val); //12345
};
```

Comment: Exists another way that it will be transparent for the user? I don't like that the user when load the module have to add the var.

Comment: @EnZo This is the standard way to do it. Why would you not want the user to pass a function argument?

Comment: My problem persists. Because nodejs do not accept
var test = 1234;
console.log(this['test']) // undefined

So my idea was pass the this object to have access to all the vars:
var mymodule = require('mymodule')(this);

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best and the only way to do it.

```
externalvar = 12345;
```

Or

```
global.externalvar = 12345;
```

Inside the module

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log(global.externalvar); //12345
};
```

But this is not working

```
var externalvar = 12345;
console.log(global.externalvar); //undefined
```